# test the significance of the marginal effects of a spatial probit model

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance, spatial, probit, marginal-effect

I'm using the CRAN package `spatialprobit` to estimate a Spatial Probit. The function `sarprobit` calculates the marginal effects that can be printed using the function `impacts`. However,the function does not report the significance of the marginal effects . I wanted to know if there was a way that this can be done in R, preferably canned, but if none are available, how would I manually calculate the significance of the posterior means of the marginal effects that were computed from the fitted model?